# How can I convert a “short[ ]” array and output as a txt/csv (human readable) in C# program?

Tags: c#

I'm building a voice recording app and would like to return a human readable file with data from Short[] array, wondering if there is a way to do it without binarize it.

More information: the 16bit short[] array is PCM **(input)** data extracted from a for loop in a C# program that keep recording audio data, and I want to add a function that can return a txt/csv file with the digitalized audio data which can be used to plot a voice frequency graph.

Attached picture is the graph that I want to plot by using the output txt data.

below is the code I have tried with "BinaryWriter" and "tostring" function and it return binary data in txt file that is not able to visualize.

in the code:

"speech_s" is the targeted short[] array
"frn_len" = 160 (20ms X 8b)

if the whole story is too complicated, **any way to return csv/txt file from short[] in C#** is more than enough.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Q2m.png)
thank you so much!!

```
short[] speech_s = new short[frn_len];
for (i = 0; i < frn_len; i++)
{
    speech_s[i] = (short)(((BufData[2 * i + 1] << 8) & 0xFF00) + ((BufData[2 * i]) & 0x00FF));

}

Jeff_txt_recorder = FileReceiveDir + "\\" + "JEFF_test.txt";
Jeff_record = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(Jeff_txt_recorder, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
for (int j = 0; j < frn_len; j++)
    Jeff_record.Write(speech_s[j].ToString());
```

Comment: Well, rather use a [`StringWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.stringwriter?view=netcore-3.1) if you want to write strings instead of binary datas

Comment: Please don't create a new account so you can reask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565700/i-have-an-array-of-shorts-short-that-i-need-to-write-out-to-a-txt-or-csv-hu#64565700

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the whole BinaryWriter stuff, and create & write to a text file/writer directly:

```
short[] speech_s = new short[frn_len];
for (i = 0; i < frn_len; i++)
{
    speech_s[i] = (short)(((BufData[2 * i + 1] << 8) & 0xFF00) + ((BufData[2 * i]) & 0x00FF));

}

Jeff_txt_recorder = FileReceiveDir + "\\" + "JEFF_test.txt";
using (var jeff_record = File.CreateText(Jeff_txt_recorder)) {
   jeff_record.WriteLine(string.Join(",", speech_s.Select(s => s.ToString()));
}
```